# Neo4j query with logical AND on relationship types instead of OR

Tags: neo4j, cypher

***UPDATE***: I've changed the graphic and example queries to make the request more clear. The basic idea is the same, but now I'm showing that there really are more than just two relationships. The idea is I want TWO of them to match, not necessarily ALL of them.

Given the following Neo4j graph:

[image: Two nodes with many relationships]

Is it possible to specify a relationship in a query that requires that *TWO* specific relationships be there for a match, but not necessarily all, without simply stating each full matching path separately?  I want a logical `AND` on the relationship types, just like we have a logical `OR` using the `|` character.

This is how you would use a logical OR with the `|` character:

```
// OR on MEMBER_OF and GRANT_GROUP_COMP
MATCH (p:Person {name:'John'})-[r:MEMBER_OF|GRANT_GROUP_COMP]->(t:Team {name:'Team 1'})
RETURN p,r,t
```

What I'm looking for is something like this, an AND with a `&` or simlar that *REQUIRES* that both relationships be present:

```
// AND type functionality in the relationship I'd like
MATCH (p:Person {name:'John'})-[r:MEMBER_OF&GRANT_GROUP_COMP]->(t:Team {name:'Team 1'})
RETURN p,r,t
```

Without having to resort to this - *which works for me just fine*:

```
// I'd like to avoid this
MATCH (p:Person {name:'John'})-[r:MEMBER_OF]->(t:Team {name:'Team 1'}),
  (p)-[r2:GRANT_GROUP_COMP]->(t)
RETURN p,r,r2,t
```

Any insight would be appreciated, but based on responses so far, it simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
MATCH (D:Person {name:'Donald'})-[r1:WORKS_AT]->
      (o:Office {code:'279'})<-[r2:SUPPORTS]-(D)
RETURN *
```

Inspired version of Dave

```
MATCH (D:Person {name:'Donald'})-[r:WORKS_AT|SUPPORTS]->(o:Office {code:'279'})
WITH D, o, collect(r) as rels, 
     collect(distinct type(r)) as tmp WHERE size(tmp) >= 2
return D, o, rels
```

**Update:**

```
MATCH (D:Person {name:'Donald'})
      -  [r: MEMBER_OF
           | GRANT_INDIRECT_ALERTS
           | GRANT_INDIRECT_COMP
           | GRANT_GROUP_ALERTS
           | GRANT_GROUP_COMP 
         ] ->
      (o:Office {code:'279'})
WITH D, o, collect(r) as rels, 
     collect(distinct type(r)) as tmp WHERE size(tmp) >= 2 AND size(tmp) <= 5
return D, o, rels
```

Comment: The problem with the first is that it only works in the simple example case. My real-world need already has something else on that other side of the (o:Office) node.  In your second example, it assumes that there are only two relationships there, while in my case I am checking that a specific two out of many are present.  That's pretty clever, though.

Comment: @MichaelOryl In the second solution, you can add as many types of relationships, how much do you want: `MATCH (D:Person {name:'Donald'})-[r:WORKS_AT|SUPPORTS|REL1|REL2|REL3]->(o:Office {code:'279'})
WITH D, o, collect(r) as rels, 
     collect(distinct type(r)) as tmp WHERE size(tmp) >= 5
return D, o, rels`

Comment: That's true, but what I mean is that there are many there, but I am only concerned with two specific ones - not that ALL are there.  My use case is access rights.  Consider that I want to see that somebody is a member of a group and has granted the group to a specific class of his or her data.  I want both relationships to match the query.  But there could be other classes of data rights granted to that group by that user, as well.  Follow me?

Comment: I've updated the question with new graphics and example queries.

Comment: @MichaelOryl f I understand you correctly - see my updated version.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't understand me still. MEMBER_OF and GRANT_GROUP_COMP must both be present for a match.  I'm concerned with those two.  Just matching any two doesn't help me.  Look at my third query in the question. That is what I am trying to accomplish. I just was looking for a logical AND operator when matching relationship types. My third query works, I just wanted it simpler.

Answer (score 2):

This query will return a result if `John` and `Team 1` have `MEMBER_OF` AND `GRANT_GROUP_COMP` relationships between them.

(This is very similar to the second answer of @stdob--, but requires the size of `types` to be exactly 2.)

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: 'John'})-[r:MEMBER_OF|GRANT_GROUP_COMP]->(t:Team {name: 'Team 1'})
WITH p, t, COLLECT(r) AS rels, COLLECT(DISTINCT type(r)) AS types
WHERE SIZE(types) = 2
RETURN p, t, rels;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the second relationship type in a `WHERE` clause. Something like this...

```
MATCH (p:Person {name:'John'})-[r:GRANT_GROUP_COMP]->(t:Team {name:'Team 1'})
WHERE (p)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(t)
RETURN *
```

Or you could make sure that the complete set is in the collection of relationship types. Something like this...

```
MATCH (p:Person {name:'John'})-[r]->(t:Team {name:'Team 1'})
with p,t,collect(type(r)) as r_types
where all(r in ['MEMBER_OF','GRANT_GROUP_COMP'] where r in r_types)
RETURN p, t, r_types
```

Comment: I appreciate the ideas - especially the second - but my reason for asking this was that I was trying to move away from a model I already have that instead used properties in a relationship and used a WHERE to check them. I wanted a cleaner/simpler query than that. I guess your second idea at least has the benefit of not using properties in the WHERE, which is a bit of a performance boost as I understand it. Properties are in a different part of the file system than the relationship types, I believe.

Comment: I would say the first one has better potential to perform better depending on the your data statistics.  If you have one relationship type that occurs less than then the other and you put that in the match statement neo4j won't evaluate past that if there are no watches. Whereas if you grab all of the relationship types between two nodes and evaluate them you are incurring more database hits. The point may be mute though if the overall data is small or the relationship type occurrences are even.

Comment: That's good feedback, Dave. I really appreciate it.  My group is new to using Neo4j, so insight like that really helps.